# How to improve performance in Oracle BLOB column read over network?

Tags: .net, oracle, performance, networking, blob

I'm comparing Sql Server and Oracle performance of reads using C#. Basically, I'm using ADO.NET and ODP.NET and obtaining similar values on both, except when I read BLOB columns on distributed machines (one machine requesting another with DB).

Important notes:

- The results are even for Sql and Oracle when testing locally.
- Latency between machines are '<1ms'

In my test, all the data are exactly the same, and I'm reading 2881 rows with some binary data on each row. The obtained results are:

- Sql Server locally: 1.6s
- Oracle locally: 1.8s (good result)
- Sql Server distributed: 1.8s
- Oracle distributed: 10.0s (problem here!)

Configurations that I'm already using on Oracle to perform better:

1. `OracleCommand.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;` (tried other positive values but with worst results)
2. `OracleCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;` (tried other positive values but with worst results)
3. `OracleReader.FetchSize = OracleReader.RowSize * 10000;` (setting before the first `Read()`)

So the question is:

- There is any other configuration I'm missing to obtain better performance when reading BLOB columns?

Other notes:

- I assumed `InitialLOBFetchSize = -1` would improve this scenario considering low latency, but didn't improved too much (with `InitialLOBFetchSize = 0` time was ~12.8s).
- Already tried some network improvement configurations on Oracle instance, but without expressive results
- Using Oracle.DataAccess.dll x64 v4.121.2.0
- Tried using managed and unmanaged Oracle drivers, with better results with the unmanaged ones (the one I was already using since the beginning)

References:

- [Poor performance getting clob field from Oracle in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838115/poor-performance-getting-clob-field-from-oracle-in-net)

Comment: Have you tried setting InitialLOBFetchSize to a bigger value like 4000? I believe this will make the driver read the lob data inline and will improve the response time.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene yes. I did try with some values and got worst results. Even with "int.MaxValue" I'm getting worst results like ~12s.

Comment: Can you define the BLOB as a LONG_RAW and get the data as a stream? In JDBC this technique improves the response time greatly.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene I'll test it. Thanks.